# clang-format, array initialisers

Tags: c++, clang-format

In our project, we sometimes initialise arrays on one line, and sometimes we initialise them as blocks. That is

`strings::UniChar const s[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};`

vs

```
strings::UniChar const s[] = 
{
  'H', 
  'e', 
  'l', 
  'l', 
  'o'
};
```

I would like to `clang-format` to be able to distinguish between the two types and not convert the second into the first one or align the elements after the opening brace. That is not like this:

```
strings::UniChar const s[] = {'H', 
                              'e', 
                              'l', 
                              'l', 
                              'o'};
```

Is there a way to achieve that using config files?

Comment: Why don't you disable clang format just for those declarations with a `/* clang-format off */`

Comment: It is one of the options I consider, I hoped there was an automated way to do that.

Answer (score 27):

Adding a comma after the last array element causes clang-format (tried with v6.0.0) to align the elements to the left side, like your second example.

```
// With a trailing comma.
char buf[] = {
  'a',
  'b',
};

// Without a trailing comma.
char buf2[] = {'a', 'b'};
```

Answer (score 10):

try "Cpp11BracedListStyle: false"

Answer (score 4):

You can force a line break with `//`:

```
strings::UniChar const s[] = {
    'H',  //
    'e',  //
    'l',  //
    'l',  //
    'o'   //
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. Works great. I had to do this in conjunction with the comma after the last element and setting `Cpp11BracedListStyle: false` to get the format I wanted for the initializer on a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Hacky workaround but it works. But you should't have to fight your formatter to get things to look the way you want.