# clang-format array initialiser over multiple lines?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'd like to be able to write the following code:

```
float positions[] =
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f
};
```

however clang-format keeps formating the initializers to be over one single line.

I can't find the setting to allow them to be either over one line or multiple lines as above. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058627/clang-format-array-initialisers) question is similar, but does not solve my problem, as it assumes the engine allows for multiple line initializations.

What setting am I missing? I have looked through the options but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Unless you have a very narrow line width that can only accommodate `-0.5f, -0.5f`, I am afraid that couldn't be quite possible with clang-format as far as I know. That is, you can choose to have either one argument per line, or several arguments that together fill up that line, but clang-format won't allow you to fill up just part of the line. For your reference, see `BinPackArguments` option.

Comment: @aafulei is there any way to disable this sort of formatting for array initialisers etc. all together?

Comment: To turn clang-format off temporarily, put the specific code between these two comment lines: `// clang-format off` and `//clang-format on` to tell clang-format not to touch that part.

Comment: @aafulei and there's no way for clang-format to just not format array initialisers globally with adding this comment each time?

Comment: `there's no way for clang-format to just not format array initialisers globally?` I am afraid not. Don't you think this is too specific?

Comment: @aafulei I disagree, if I can do something such as "AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine" I feel similar options could be catered for for initializer list alignment. Anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrangement doesn't make any sense from a formatter point of view. You have an initializer list and asking the formatter to arrange it in two elements per line. But an initializer list has no semantics, nothing at all to even remotely suggest that its elements are related in pairs.

If your elements should be grouped in twos then most likely you need to actually "group" them in a structure that makes sense. This is not only for formatting, but for code sanity first and foremost. E.g.:

```
struct Point { float x; float y; };

Point positions[] =
{
    {-0.5f, -0.5f},
    {0.5f, -0.5f},
    {0.5f,  0.5f},
    {-0.5f,  0.5f}
};
```

---

Also I strongly recommend to stop using C arrays. Use `std::vector` or `std::array`:

```
struct Point { float x; float y; };

std::array<Point, 4> positions =
{{
    {-0.5f, -0.5f},
    {0.5f, -0.5f},
    {0.5f,  0.5f},
    {-0.5f,  0.5f}
}};
```

Comment: This is probably what I would do in an actual code base, but I am actually following a tutorial and so this is for education purposes, and I'd still like to ability to disable array formatting, but what you've said definitely does make sense - I'm not sure I'd actually run into this problem. I usually would use a std::array.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by wrapping code in `clang-format off/on` comment. clang-format formatting this in one line but if you want to temporary disable clang-format you can do it with:

```
// clang-format off
float positions[] =
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f
};
// clang-format on
```