# Clang-format array initializer one per line

Tags: c++, clang-format

Clang-format, given an array of structs with initializers, is putting two items per line:

```
sym keywords[] = {
    {0, 0, "C"},           {0, 0, "T"},
    {0, 0, "V"},           {0, 0, "ax"},
    {0, 0, "bool"},        {0, 0, "break"},
    ...
    {0, 0, "val"},         {0, 0, "vector"},
    {0, 0, "version"},     {0, 0, "void"},
    {0, 0, "while"},
};
```

How can I get it to just put one item per line?

[clang-format, array initialisers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058627/clang-format-array-initialisers) is the closest I have been able to find to a discussion of this problem, but neither of the proposed solutions has any effect; `Cpp11BracedListStyle: false` does the same thing except with extra spaces between the braces, and as you can see in the above, making sure there is a comma after the last item, doesn't help.

Comment: hi did you find any solution? any update?

Comment: @Ted Erm, the solution I found was to switch the project that was complex enough to generate such constructs from C++ to Java (for other reasons, granted), that's probably not very useful from your perspective, sorry!

Comment: @Ted I might have a solution, not sure if you are still interested.

Comment: Try: `PackConstructorInitializersStyle` value `CurrentLine`. This requires clang-format 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but `ArrayInitializerAlignmentStyle` set to `left` might achieve that result. This option was added with `clang-format` version 13.

At least my current settings turn your code into:

```
sym keywords[] = {
    {0, 0, "C"      },
    {0, 0, "T"      },
    {0, 0, "V"      },
    {0, 0, "ax"     },
    {0, 0, "bool"   },
    {0, 0, "break"  },
    {0, 0, "val"    },
    {0, 0, "vector" },
    {0, 0, "version"},
    {0, 0, "void"   },
    {0, 0, "while"  },
};
```

If I remove that setting I get something similar to your result.

My current settings, which probably don't do what you expect them at other locations:

```
---
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignArrayOfStructures: Left
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignConsecutiveMacros: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
ColumnLimit: 120
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always
FixNamespaceComments: true
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
PackConstructorInitializers: NextLine
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 10
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 10
PenaltyBreakComment: 10
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 10
PenaltyBreakString: 10
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 10
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
Standard: Latest
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

Comment: I have clang-format 14.0.0 and your suggestion gives me errors: `.clang-format:30:1: error: unknown key 'ArrayInitializerAlignmentStyle'`

Comment: @zwol `ArrayInitializerAlignmentStyle` is not a key, it's the type of the `AlignArrayOfStructures` setting.  So `AlignArrayOfStructures: Left` is what you are looking for.